# How to have Pulumi adopt an Akamai Property

Tags: akamai, pulumi

I have an Akamai Property created manually that I would like to import (adopt) through Pulumi. The [Pulumi docs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/guides/adopting/import/) have an example for AWS services, but is it possible to adopt an Akamai resource through Pulumi? If so what would the import command look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of the Pulumi Akamai provider (1.0.0) now supports this.

```
pulumi import akamai:index/property:Property example prp_123
```

See https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/akamai/property/#import for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current upstream akamai provider doesn't support `import` at this time so it is not possible.